# Gcc in windows + pcre2 how can do it?

Tags: windows, gcc, msys2, pcre2

Hi guys  i try to add PCRE2 in GCC in windows, but is very Hell for me , explain my  step,
in windows i have installed MSYS2_64bit, like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfVqzNU3gPg , after i download a PCRE2 and unzip it in C: and after i create new folder call build (c:/pcre2/pcre2-10.39/build), after install cmake tools , i run it choice  a source (c:/pcre2/pcre2-10.39) , choice  a build (c:/pcre2/pcre2-10.39/build)dir , choice MSYS makefile and generate , after this i went in build folder by MSYS shell and  run command Make    , but  return

````
$ make
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pcre2-8-static.dir/src/pcre2_auto_possess.c.obj
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcre2-8-static.dir/build.make:77: CMakeFiles/pcre2-8-static.dir/src/pcre2_auto_possess.c.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/pcre2-8-static.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2```

anyone can help me ?? thanks
````

Comment: MSYS2 provides a pcre2 package. You can download it instead of building pcre2 yourself.

Comment: o yeeaa   thanksssss  so much and  how ? i am not expert msys

Comment: Here's the instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/2752075 After you do what it says, run `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre2` to install pcre2.